# How to get out of being suspended by bash console?

Tags: bash, shell

In unix-like system terminal, I sometimes used some commands incorrectly and make bash don't know what to do, but just pending on a newline.
e.g.

```
grep 'word' -R
```

Then how can I make up to the mistake, or get rid of it to retry?

Looks like CTRL+C can help me return free, but not sure if this is a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if control+c is not working you can press ctrl+z which will send the process background. Once the process is in background you can kill it by using
kill %1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> repeatedly is the "usual" way to get out of commands waiting for additional input, or canceling running foregroud processes. You will end up with the normal shell prompt.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> clears the screen, which might also come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

For applications taking input, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> will end the input. For example, `tail` without any parameters will tail standard input, so you can start typing on the screen. And when you finish (and you want it to actually tail), you press CTRL+D.